# How to convert uint8 to uint256 bitmap in solidity?

Tags: solidity, data-types, math, type-casting, bit-manipulation

Say I have a `uint8` with binary value `0000_1001` i.e. `8+1=9` in decimal. How do I convert this `uint8` in a gas efficient way to a `uint256` which represents a bitmap?, such that in this example the 9th bit(1-indexed) is initialised to `1` and all remaining 255 bits initialised to `0` i.e. `...0_0001_0000_0000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the shift operator.

In your example:

```js
uint8 value = 9;
uint256 mask = 1 << value;
```

See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#integers

Comment: This does answer my question, however it may be useful to indicate the use of a bitwise OR i.e. mask = mask | (1 << value) in the case that mask is already initialised to some value as is the case in my use.